# How to make pop up div stand inside page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

I am having css issues about the pop that a bit out of the web page

Here is how it's look:
[image]

here is my code base:

```
let popupStyles = {};

if (this.props.useRefToPosition) {
  popupStyles = {
    position: 'fixed',
    left: this.state.leftRefPosition,
    top: this.state.topRefPosition - (this.state.popupHeight + 10) ,
    bottom: 'unset'
  };
}

    <div
      style={popupStyles}
      className={`tool-tip-popup ${pos.toString()} ${(this.state.show && this.props.disabled !== true) ? "show" : ""}`}
      id="tool-tip-popup-question"
      data-testid={this.props.dataTestId ? `${this.props.dataTestId}-popup` : null}
      ref={this.popupRef}
    >
      {this.tooltipPopup(tooltipId)}
    </div>
```

Comment: anyone have idea how to fix this error?

Comment: This is the problem of the static tooltips. You need to calculate if the tooltip goes out of the container and if so, to display it to the left.